# How to make list of system fonts?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a program that will show a list of my installed fonts in a system. Can this be done through JS?
The result I want to see this:

[List of the system fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEnCB.png)

Comment: You'd only be able to use browser fonts, plus any loaded from the server. For a list of fonts: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.